# Bukkit Player check achievements

Tags: bukkit, achievements

I don't know what I should put into player.getAdvancementProgress(Here).

```
if (player.getAdvancementProgress().isDone()) {

}
```

Maybe someone knows something?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [`Advancement`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/advancement/Advancement.html) object, specially the advancement that you are looking for informations.

You can get it with `Bukkit.getAdvancement(NamespacedKey.fromString("advancement/name"))` where **advancement/name** can be `nether/all_potions` for example. You can get all [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Advancement#List_of_advancements) (column: "Resource location). If you are getting it from command, I suggest you to add tab complete.

Example of TAB that show only not-done success :

```java
@Override
public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!(sender instanceof Player))
        return list;
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    String prefix = arg[arg.length - 1].toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT); // the begin of the searched advancement
    Bukkit.advancementIterator().forEachRemaining((a) -> {
        AdvancementProgress ap = p.getAdvancementProgress(a);
        if((prefix.isEmpty() || a.getKey().getKey().toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) && !ap.isDone() && !a.getKey().getKey().startsWith("recipes"))
            list.add(a.getKey().getKey());
    });
    return list;
}
```

Then, in the command you can do like that:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg) {
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) // not allowed for no-player
        return false;
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    // firstly: try to get advancement
    Advancement a = Bukkit.getAdvancement(NamespacedKey.fromString(arg[0]));
    if(a == null)
        a = Bukkit.getAdvancement(NamespacedKey.minecraft(arg[0]));
    if(a == null) // can't find it
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Failed to find success " + arg[0]);
    else { // founded :
        AdvancementProgress ap = p.getAdvancementProgress(a);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Achivement " + a.getKey().getKey() + " stay: " + ChatColor.YELLOW + String.join(", ", ap.getRemainingCriteria().stream().map(this::getCleaned).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
    return false;
}
    
private String getCleaned(String s) { // this method is only to make content easier to read
    String[] args = s.split("/");
    return args[args.length - 1].replace(".png", "").replace(".jpg", "").replace("minecraft:", "").replace("_", " ");
}
```

Else, if you want to get all advancements, you should use `Bukkit.advancementIterator()`.

Comment: can I check if a player got an achevement?

Comment: *advancement xD

Comment: such as you wrote in your question, but with the advancement instance that you like as I show in my answer :) like `player.getAdvancementProgress(ad).isDone()`